# Get quicktime API for windows

Tags: windows, api, quicktime, audiovideoplayback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing just Quicktime libraries on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74586/installing-just-quicktime-libraries-on-windows)

can anyone tell me if there is an QUICKTIME API for windows? i just found some documentation, but all it was explained in objective c. is there the same in any other programming languages?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Varun

Comment: What programming language, specifically, are you interested in?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Quicktime API for windows that you can use native C/C++ with. However to get started with Quicktime I would recommend that you experiment first with the QT Activex component in VB.NET or C#. This is by far the fastest and easiest way to get started. If you install Quicktime on your windows machine you can reference the Acivex component in Visual Studio. A good book on on the Quicktime Activex for .NET is "Quicktime for .NET and COM developers".

Answer (score 0):

Apple has mostly replaced QuickTime with other APIs that are not available on Windows such as QTKit. The QuickTime Windows SDK has not been updated for several years. The QuickTime for Windows SDK does not support Objective C development or any of the more modern Objective C APIs.

You can search the Apple developer library for QuickTime documentation but ignore material that's about QTKit, AVFoundation or Objective C.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/index.html#section=Frameworks&topic=QuickTime